# How to start a process deployed in jbpm-console from my own rest service?

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to create a rest service that is domain specific. It accepts orders in domain format and calls some jbpm6 processes. Lets assume, all the processes called on behalf of a customer order are supposed to run inside same JTA transaction.

In a standalone application, it is straightforward to embed jbpm6 engine inside my rest service.

But I want the process instance visualisation offered by jbpm-console. So I built a kjar and deployed it inside kie container.

Now how do I start and manipulate multiple processes deployed inside kie from within my own rest service? The requirement is: processes called on behalf of one customer order must run in same JTA transaction.

Comment: I've got a similar problem and the fact that documentation for version 6 doesn't exist (or at least is not googlable) doesn't help. I get the following exception when trying to navigate to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/ or any other REST endpoint:

FAILURE /jbpm-console/rest/server/resources Could not find resource for relative : /server/resources of full path: http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/server/resources org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for relative : /server/resources of full path: http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/server/...(long)

Comment: We switched to Camunda BPMN engine. It has a cleaner deployment model unlike JBPM6's Kie workbench. In Camunda, the core engine can be deployed as separate container service (like JMS), which can then be shared across multiple REST applications. Camunda cockpit (UI) is a separate WAR and it uses REST api to communicate with core engine, unlike in JBPM6 where core engine runs inside a child classloader created by Kie workbech - that makes it impossible to run it inside my own transaction.